# Solr use search result of first query as the index for second query

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a `Solr` index which consists of 10 fields. They are given below.

```
firstname, lastname, middlename, dob, gender, phone, email, address, city, state
```

The index consists of some 10 M records. I am trying to find best match for some incoming records. Suppose one such incoming record is like below.

```
John, Smith, P, 19980923, M, 9896574300, john@jj.com, James Street, Houston, TX
```

So my Solr query is given below.

```
firstname:John OR lastname:Smith OR middlename:P OR dob:19980923 OR gender:M OR phone:9896574300 OR email:john@jj.com OR address:"James Street" OR city:Houston OR state:TX
```

The problem is that the query takes time even though I limit the result set to top 100 only. This is because majority of the records have the state value as TX and city is also Houston and because of it Solr takes time to rank and sort all these records.

My objective is to reduce the number of results returned by Solr query. So first I would like to use the below query

```
firstname:John OR lastname:Smith OR middlename:P OR dob:19980923 OR phone:9896574300 OR email:john@jj.com OR address:"James Street"
```

In the above case it returns only minimum number of records and on top of that I would like to run actual query as below so that it returns most relevant record on top

```
firstname:John OR lastname:Smith OR middlename:P OR dob:19980923 OR gender:M OR phone:9896574300 OR email:john@jj.com OR address:"James Street" OR city:Houston OR state:TX
```

Is it possible to achieve it in single query? Using OR condition may fetch all records, so I want to fetch only the minimum number of records on the basis of few fields values initially and then apply the actual query on top of it

Comment: In your second example - do you want to re-score the documents returned from your first query, based on the second query? You don't want to intersect the two result sets? (which would mean that both queries run from an empty state both times). For the former case, you can use the re-rank query parser: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_4/query-re-ranking.html

Comment: did you tried with filter query fq?

Comment: Filter query will not work in my use case. If I use filter query it will return only those records which contains that term. I don't want to intersect two result sets because in such case it will run both the queries and it may take time. I think re-rank query parser is the one I can look into. Thank you Mats and Abhijit for your help